# How to extract the largest object, based on an attribute, from a vector?

Tags: c++, stl

Let's say I have a bunch of `Donut` objects, and each of these donuts has a public integer attribute `diameter`.  If I have a vector of donuts, how can I extract the donut with the smallest or largest diameter?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You use `std::min_element` and `std::max_element`.  For example, given a `std::vector<int>`:

```
std::vector<int> v;
std::vector<int>::iterator it = std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end());
// 'it' points to the largest element in 'v'
```

If you want to compare elements using something other than `operator<` (which is used by default), you need to write a custom comparator:

```
bool compare_donut_diameters(const Donut& x, const Donut& y)
{
    return x.diameter < y.diameter;
}
```

Used as:

```
std::vector<Donut> v;
std::vector<Donut>::iterator it = std::max_element(v.begin, v.end(), 
                                                   compare_donut_diameters);
```

You can also implement the comparator using a function object (also called a functor) or if your compiler supports lambda expressions you can use a lambda:

```
auto it = std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end(), 
    [](const Donut& x, const Donut& y) {  return x.diameter < y.diameter; });
```

Comment: Yep, it's certainly going to take a while to figure out how to use lambda functions in 80 columns ;-)

Comment: @Steve:  Seriously! I think I reformatted that last example four times...  It's a good thing widescreen displays are more prevalent.  240 character lines here I come!

Comment: c++0x looks so foreign... "auto", anonymous functions... pfft :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::min_element`:

```
// You can use a functor instead!
bool compare_donut(const Donut& lhs, const Donut& rhs)
{ return lhs.diameter < rhs.diameter; }
...
// min_donut is an iterator to the smallest donut in donut_vector.
std::vector<Donut>::iterator min_donut = 
   std::min_element(donut_vector.begin(), donut_vector.end(), compare_donut);
```

If you want to get the largest, you can use `std::max_element` with the same comparator.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the std::max_element/std::min_element algorithm in combination with an operator< that compares using the diameter attribute or an user provided compare function.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max_element/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min_element/